# 'using' before a variable inside a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I understand `using`directive can be used to refer to a namespace.
Could anyone please tell what it means when it is used in front of a variable `G4NtupleIterator` or a class name `G4AnalysisManager` as in the following example?

```
namespace G4Csv 
{
  using G4NtupleIterator = std::vector<tools::wcsv::ntuple*>::iterator;

  using G4AnalysisManager = G4CsvAnalysisManager; 
}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, it's C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `using` directive introduces a symbol into the current scope.  If that scope includes a namespace, then it will be part of that namespace but not others, including the global namespace.

In your example you could refer to `G4Csv::G4NtupleIterator` or `G4Csv::G4AnalysisManager`.